# Mostrar o maior valor de um campo, juntamente com o nome do campo

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou com uma duvida enorme.

Preciso mostrar na minha tabela, na pagina inicial do meu site, qual campo da minha tabela tem o maior valor e junto deste campo, mostrar não somente o maior valor mas também o nome da pessoa que tem este valor.

Explicando melhor: este campo de maior valor é quantidade de vezes que um aluno pegou livros na biblioteca.
o codigo deverá mostrar na pagina inicial qual campo é o de maior valor de emprestimos e mostrar o nome do aluno.

no meu codigo, consegui mostrar apenas o campo de maior valor o nome do aluno não consegui fazer aparecer.

veja meu codigo.
este é apenas da tabela em questão.

```html
<table width="757" border="3" align="center" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#006699">
  <tr>
    <td width="572" align="center">
      <p>Selecione <span class="destaques">EMPRESTIMOS</span> para emprestar o livro pego paraseu aluno.</p>
      <p>Selecione <span class="destaques">RELATORIO DE EMPRESTIMOS</span> para remover o livro do nome dos alunos.</p>
      <p>Selecione <span class="destaques">CADASTRO</span> para cadastrar <span class="destaques">LIVROS</span> - <span class="destaques">ALUNOS</span>.</p>
      <p>Selecione <span class="destaques">RELATORIOS</span> para ver a relacao de <span class="destaques">LIVROS</span> - <span class="destaques">ALUNOS</span> - <span class="destaques">AUTORES</span> - <span class="destaques">EDITORAS</span> - <span class="destaques">EMPRESTIMOS</span>.</p>
    </td>
    <? $consulta=m ysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query( 'SELECT MAX(vezes) FROM cadastro_alunos')); $nome=$ consulta [ 'nome']; $max=i ntval($consulta[ 'MAX(vezes)']); ?>
    <td width="168" align="center" bgcolor="#FFCC00">Aluno (a) que mais se destacou em Leitura é:
      <? echo $nome ?> <font class="bem_vindo"></font> - com
      <? echo $max ?>Livros</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Alguem tem alguma ideia de como fazer para mostrar o nome do aluno, juntamente com o maior valor???

grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revendo seu código, creio que você nem precise usar `max()`, basta usar a query:

```
SELECT nome,vezes FROM cadastro_aluno order by vezes desc limit 1
```

**Veja funcionando: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9de09b/10/0**

**Referências:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: vou tentar aqui

Comment: @GuilhermeHenrique editei o código.

Comment: fiz conforme vc descreveu, mas algo ainda está errado. depois de declardo o nome na query, ate inseri a serie do aluno, no codigo mostra nome e serie, junto do valor, mas não está mostrando o maior valor, mas sim um valor aleatorio, o maior valor na minha tabela é 9 com nome de João Pedro, na pagina está mostrando Ana Luiza com o valor de 3. o  que será que pode ser?

Comment: @GuilhermeHenrique editei a pergunta, com outra abordagem de solução

Comment: agora finalmente consegui, não usei o max(), mas alterei a estrutura da query, da mesma forma que uso nas outras paginas que uso o select. ficou assim '$sql_visualizar = mysql_query ("SELECT serie, nome, vezes FROM cadastro_alunos order by vezes desc limit 1");
 while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array ($sql_visualizar)){
  $serie = $linha ['serie'];
  $nome = $linha ['nome'];
  $max = $linha ['vezes'];'. 

ai deu certinho agora.

vlw Diego